# jQuery chosen styling

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-chosen

based on the awesome answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734982/jquery-chosen-plugin-customize-format-text-of-option-in-select) question I have been able to style my `<select>` box exactly how I want it, using jQuery Chosen.
But as soon as a user starts typing in the search bar, the mark-up gets lost.

Example is found [here](http://staging.topografieindeklas.nl/account/registreren/), just above the form submit button.

How could this be avoided/corrected?

```
$('.populate-school .gfield_select').on('chosen:showing_dropdown keyup change', function()
  {
    $('.chosen-results .active-result, .chosen-single span').html(function()
    {
        var val = $(this).html().split(',');
        return '<strong>'+val[0]+'</strong><br/>'+val[1];
    });
  });
```

Comment: I am not experiencing what you are describing.

Comment: I see it.  Looks like you're in a race against the plugin; it's updating its output after your function tries to rewrite that output.  Personally I'd just modify the plugin code to produce the desired out put in the first place; otherwise you probably need to  just `setTimeout` delay your change handler by a bit to ensure your code runs last.

Comment: You put first option as a default which creates "undefined" values in inspector, instead put default in placeholder like in the example <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging more the comment of @Daniel turned out to be true.
In the end I've dropped the Chosen library in favor of [Select2](https://select2.org). Turns out to be a lot more flexible and supported!